# Google chrome css doesn't update unless clear cache

Tags: css, google-chrome, caching

I'm trying to work in my local server but I have to clear my cache every time if I want to see changes on the css rules.

There is any way to control Google Chrome cache?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

1. Open `DevTools`
2. Open `Settings` (bottom right or use `F1` shortcut)
3. Check `Disable cache (while DevTools is open)`

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/settings#general

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me to see changes in @imported css files.

Comment: Thank you!  This has been driving me crazy for months!

Comment: If I push the css changes over live server, then it does not appears until we refresh the cache, how to resolve this issue? I mean the public users don't know about the changes.

Comment: Thank you for this! GC drives me nuts with the aggresive cacheing

Comment: The strangest thing was happening while I was experiencing this annoyance...Some of the margin, padding, spacing changes I was making to the css file was actually verifiable when I refreshed the page, however just not all of the changes. Changing the setting as noted here was exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: just FYI, it's a checkbox at the top right corner (under network section).

Comment: The "clear your cache" and "disable cache in dev tools" solutions only help the developer.  It doesn't help the user community.  I can't tell everyone in the user community to "clear your cache."  I have petitioned Google for YEARS to please move "Disable Cache" into the Settings menu where Group Policy can ensure that it is enabled.  It falls on deaf ears at Google, unfortunately.

Answer (score 51):

CTRL+F5 : to refresh the page by clearing GG chrome cache.

Comment: CMD - SHFT - R on a mac

Answer (score 11):

1. Open up your **Developer Tools** then click the icon on the top right

[image: Google Chrome menu]

2. In settings --> preferences scroll down to find "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" and click on the box to select the option.

[image]

If you are still having the problem, and the page works on other browsers, then the easy fix could be to just uninstall Google Chrome and do a fresh install of the latest version. I ran into this problem and it was the best fix instead of the headache of tracking down a complicated fix or outdated posts that no longer work. After you have Chrome reinstalled, repeat the steps above to disable cache.

Comment: In 2017, this helped me in actually locating the setting

Answer (score 11):

Following this solution here helped me reloading the css : https://wpreset.com/force-reload-cached-css/

Instead of requesting the file doing the following :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/variabledocument.css" type="text/css" />
```

Request id by adding a parameter (the name of the parameter doesn't matter) at the end of the file :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/variabledocument.css?refreshcss=1" type="text/css" />
```

This will request the new css file. Whenever you make a change to your css file, you just have to change either the parameter name, value or both and the server will request it again.

This is very useful when you have no control over the browsers of your clients and it requests no action on their part.

Comment: Simple and effective. Best of all it has kind of a similar "Versioning" method for future updates. Couldn't believe the trouble I had updating a simple CSS file!

Comment: Having issues with subsequent deployments.
This method is a nice solution I can centralize in my base web page class for all files. such as appending the build date of the DLL so they only change when the application is recompiled and deployed. 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/variabledocument.css?BD=20201209094326" type="text/css" />`
Should work for script files with the same issue too.

Answer (score 8):

You can do any of the following options:-

1. Install a [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn/reviews?hl=en) like Clear Cache to clear cache by clicking on icon.
2. Use **Incognito Mode** and browser your website in incognito mode. Incognito mode won't disable cache clearly. Disabling cache completely may slow down your browsing experience.
3. Use chrome's features like Hard Reload (Clear cache and hard reload). [Read this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969315/whats-the-difference-between-normal-reload-hard-reload-and-empty-cache-a)
4. As @Vitaly mentioned, Use Developer Tool settings to disable cache completely.

Choose what fits you :)

Answer (score 2):

More tools > Developer Tools
Then right click the refresh button on the browser.
You will get three options. Select "Empty Cache and Hard Reload".

This will only impact the active tab.

Answer (score 1):

To Control Google Chrome Cache you can do following steps:

1. Disable the cache (while DevTools is open)
2. Close the Chrome Browser
3. Clear the Cache with a cleaner software (such as CC Cleaner)
4. Open Chrome browser

Comment: doesn't help me at all... :(

Answer (score 1):

Shift-F5 to reload the page worked for me on Chrome 61.0.3163.100

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on JGallardo's [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39964405/473040)  in 2022
In Chrome version  100.0.4896.88 in order to `Disable the cache (while DevTools is open)` the setting looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution of SylvainB2347 with adding some parameter to the include statement. This really makes Chrome to reload the resource as it assumes it must have changed.
I just wanted to optimize this solution a little, to make it automatic but not breaking the caching principle.

My solution is to use the PHP function [filemtime(*filename*)](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_filemtime.asp) which returns the timestamp of last content modification. I use it as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.css?foo=<?php echo filemtime("index.css"); ?>">
```

which produces this in HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.css?foo=1673508035">
```

When I modify `index.css`, the timestamp changes. This way the browser is forced to reload the resource only if it's been modified since the last visit. And I don't have to rewrite anything manually.