# Chrome (+FF) shows weird duplicated CSS

Tags: css, less

Started today (Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)) - chrome won't clear old css when and actually shows the older versions as part of the css loaded. What event stranger is that it points to the same line-number.

[image]

Any idea - been searching around and did not come with anything so far.

**Update:** "disable cache" is marked, closing and opening did not help nor incognito tab or clearing all related data. + no service workers

**Update 2:** Happens in FF as well - CSS file looks fine

**Update 3:** The problem was in the concatenation process (of style files)

Comment: Developer tools | Network | Disable Cache

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google chrome css doesn't update unless clear cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300400/google-chrome-css-doesnt-update-unless-clear-cache)

Comment: Did you try to open your page in incognito mode?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately did not help - still shows same weird pattern

Comment: What about other browsers?

Comment: did you look at your http headers?

Comment: Try to open a css file through chrome, and refresh ti there and see is it okay there?

Comment: @Viktor Well, happens in FF as well :\ so, not a chrome issue - CSS file looks fine - what can cause this weird pattern?

Comment: @DrorElovits anything. We need to see the code

Comment: Server / CDN caching

Comment: Are you sure you putted the new file at right place :D just wondering?

Comment: Looking into sourcemap issues - will update

Comment: Ok, so... don't know how I did not see it before - I concatenated already compiled file into same file over and over. Thanks all you guys - sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try CTRL + F5 for a clean refresh

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this checkbox is checked in Developer tools | Preferences | Network

[image]

Then try to refresh with `Ctrl + R` (`Cmd + R` on Mac)