# Bootstrap 4 - Change the background color of the active class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm simply trying to change the background-color of the active Bootstrap's class but its not working atm.

For that, i've a second .css who's named custom.css and i've tried many things, such as:

```
.navbar-dark .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-dark .nav-item .nav-link:active,
.navbar-dark .nav-item .nav-link:focus,
.navbar-dark .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
    color: #00B159;
}

.navbar .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar .nav-item .nav-link:active,
.navbar .nav-item .nav-link:focus,
.navbar .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
    color: #00B159;
}

.active {
    background: rgba(165, 168, 168, 0.329);
}
```

But sadly, nothing is working :D

I'm using a ViewBag to make the addClas active (it's working great since the active page is displayed in blank) :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        if (@ViewBag.ActiveMenu != null) {
            $('#' + '@ViewBag.ActiveMenu').addClass('active');
        };
    });
</script>
```

Here's the full nav's code :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark fixed-top" style="background-color:#5AC5F1">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Home/Index">
            <img src="/images/logo_header.png" height="40" width="40">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
                @if (@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("isAuth") == "true")
                {
                    <li class="nav-link" id="MyProfile">
                        @Html.ActionLink("My Profile", "Index", "Contacts", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-link" id="EventHistory">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Registration History", "Index", "History", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-link" id="Registration">
                        @Html.ActionLink("New Registration", "Index", "Registration", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you provide a JS Fiddle? Should be way easier to solve it then.

Comment: Well when I make it on Fiddle it works >.> My problem is that it seems the browser doesn't consider my overrided css file with the .active in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import you CSS file after the imported bootstrap one. The last css file overrides the main one.

So you said your files are written like this:

```
<link href="~/css/bootstrap1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<link href="~/css/custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I think that reading [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913131/can-one-css-file-take-priority-over-another-css-file) will help you understand how css files take priority.

Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300400/google-chrome-css-doesnt-update-unless-clear-cache) discusses how cache works on Chrome. You can just disable it for less inconvenience.

Comment: I already do that and it works for other classes :
    <link href="~/css/bootstrap1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: use a ` ! important` tag whenever you define your class.

Comment: Still the same. When I inspect it with Chrome i can see that he still pick the Bootstrap's css. Can't figure out why!

Comment: Ok... i don't know HOW but it works now.. I've just refreshed the page for 20x to try something else and TADAM >_> Maybe my cache... Thx!

Comment: @Korpin I am writing an explanation, give me a minute. Gonna update my answer

Comment: @Korpin hope that this will explain things a bit more in depth for you.