# How to change the color of your Dash app?

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash

Im trying to create a black dashboard, so I've grabbed a css stylesheet which should make my dashboard black. From reading the documents I understand that if you create a folder named assets in the root of your app directory and include your CSS or JavaScript files in that folder. Dash will automatically serve all of the files that are included in this folder. So I have the following structure:

```
dashapp
    |--assets
        |-- style.css
    |--data
        |-- stockdata2.csv
    |-- app.py
```

**When I run my code I get the following output:**

[image]

**I want my desired output to be like below, so with a black layout color:**

[image]

This is my code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import os

# Load data
df = pd.read_csv('c:\data\EK\Desktop\Python Microsoft Visual Studio\dashapp\data\stockdata2.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

#Initialize the application
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

#define de app
app.layout=html.Div(
    children=[
        html.Div(className='row',
            children=[
                html.Div(className='four columns div-user-controls'),
                html.Div(className='eight columns div-for-charts bg-grey'),
                html.H2('Dash - STOCK PRICES'),
                html.P('''Visualising time series with Plotly - Dash'''),
                html.P('''Pick one or more stocks from the dropdown below.'''),
                dcc.Graph(id='timeseries',
                    config={'displayModeBar': False},
                    animate=True,
                    figure=px.line(df,
                                    x='Date',
                                    y='value',
                                    color='stock',
                                    template='plotly_dark').update_layout(
                                            {'plot_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                                                'paper_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'})
                                    )

            ]
        )
    ]
)

#Run the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

**style.css looks like this:**

```css
/* Table of contents ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
Taken from https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css
- Grid
- Base Styles
 - Typography
 - Links
 - Buttons
 - Forms
 - Lists
 - Code
 - Tables
 - Spacing
 - Utilities
 - Clearing
 - Media Queries
 - Custom App CSS */


/* Grid –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column, .columns {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* For devices larger than 400px */
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .container {
      width: 85%;
      padding: 0;
 }
}
/* For devices larger than 550px */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  .container {
      width: 80%;
 }
  .column, .columns {
      margin-left: 4%;
 }
  .column:first-child, .columns:first-child {
      margin-left: 0;
 }
  .one.column, .one.columns {
      width: 4.66666666667%;
 }
  .two.columns {
      width: 13.3333333333%;
 }
  .three.columns {
      width: 22%;
 }
  .four.columns {
      width: 30.6666666667%;
 }
  .five.columns {
      width: 39.3333333333%;
 }
  .six.columns {
      width: 48%;
 }
  .seven.columns {
      width: 56.6666666667%;
 }
  .eight.columns {
      width: 65.3333333333%;
 }
  .nine.columns {
      width: 74.0%;
 }
  .ten.columns {
      width: 82.6666666667%;
 }
  .eleven.columns {
      width: 91.3333333333%;
 }
  .twelve.columns {
      width: 100%;
      margin-left: 0;
 }
  .one-third.column {
      width: 30.6666666667%;
 }
  .two-thirds.column {
      width: 65.3333333333%;
 }
  .one-half.column {
      width: 48%;
 }
 /* Offsets */
  .offset-by-one.column, .offset-by-one.columns {
      margin-left: 8.66666666667%;
 }
  .offset-by-two.column, .offset-by-two.columns {
      margin-left: 17.3333333333%;
 }
  .offset-by-three.column, .offset-by-three.columns {
      margin-left: 26%;
 }
  .offset-by-four.column, .offset-by-four.columns {
      margin-left: 34.6666666667%;
 }
  .offset-by-five.column, .offset-by-five.columns {
      margin-left: 43.3333333333%;
 }
  .offset-by-six.column, .offset-by-six.columns {
      margin-left: 52%;
 }
  .offset-by-seven.column, .offset-by-seven.columns {
      margin-left: 60.6666666667%;
 }
  .offset-by-eight.column, .offset-by-eight.columns {
      margin-left: 69.3333333333%;
 }
  .offset-by-nine.column, .offset-by-nine.columns {
      margin-left: 78.0%;
 }
  .offset-by-ten.column, .offset-by-ten.columns {
      margin-left: 86.6666666667%;
 }
  .offset-by-eleven.column, .offset-by-eleven.columns {
      margin-left: 95.3333333333%;
 }
  .offset-by-one-third.column, .offset-by-one-third.columns {
      margin-left: 34.6666666667%;
 }
  .offset-by-two-thirds.column, .offset-by-two-thirds.columns {
      margin-left: 69.3333333333%;
 }
  .offset-by-one-half.column, .offset-by-one-half.columns {
      margin-left: 52%;
 }
}
/* Base Styles –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/* NOTE html is set to 62.5% so that all the REM measurements throughout Skeleton are based on 10px sizing. So basically 1.5rem = 15px :) */
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
  font-size: 1.5em;
 /* currently ems cause chrome bug misinterpreting rems on body element */
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}

/* Typography –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
  letter-spacing: -.1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.6rem;
  line-height: 1.25;
  letter-spacing: -.1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.8rem;
  margin-top: 1.8rem;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 3.0rem;
  line-height: 1.3;
  letter-spacing: -.1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  line-height: 1.35;
  letter-spacing: -.08rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: 1.2rem;
}
h5 {
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: -.05rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.6rem;
  margin-top: 0.6rem;
}
h6 {
  font-size: 2.0rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  margin-top: 0.75rem;
}
p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
/* Blockquotes –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
blockquote {
  border-left: 4px lightgrey solid;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  margin-left: 0rem;
}
/* Links –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
a {
  color: #1EAEDB;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover {
  color: #0FA0CE;
}
/* Buttons –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.rc-slider-track{
  background-color: #007eff
}

.rc-slider-rail{
  background-color: #505050
}


.main-svg{
  font-family: "Open Sans Semi Bold"
}

.gtitle{
  font-family: "Open Sans Semi Bold" !important
}

.g-title{
  font-family: "Open Sans Semi Bold"
}


.button, button, input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], input[type="button"] {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 38px;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.button:hover, button:hover, input[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="reset"]:hover, input[type="button"]:hover, .button:focus, button:focus, input[type="submit"]:focus, input[type="reset"]:focus, input[type="button"]:focus {
  color: #333;
  border-color: #888;
  outline: 0;
}
.button.button-primary, button.button-primary, input[type="submit"].button-primary, input[type="reset"].button-primary, input[type="button"].button-primary {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #33C3F0;
  border-color: #33C3F0;
}
.button.button-primary:hover, button.button-primary:hover, input[type="submit"].button-primary:hover, input[type="reset"].button-primary:hover, input[type="button"].button-primary:hover, .button.button-primary:focus, button.button-primary:focus, input[type="submit"].button-primary:focus, input[type="reset"].button-primary:focus, input[type="button"].button-primary:focus {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #1EAEDB;
  border-color: #1EAEDB;
}
/* Forms –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
input[type="email"], input[type="number"], input[type="search"], input[type="text"], input[type="tel"], input[type="url"], input[type="password"], textarea, select {
  height: 38px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
 /* The 6px vertically centers text on FF, ignored by Webkit */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
 /*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080413/why-doesnt-input-inherit-the-font-from-body*/
}
/* Removes awkward default styles on some inputs for iOS */
input[type="email"], input[type="number"], input[type="search"], input[type="text"], input[type="tel"], input[type="url"], input[type="password"], textarea {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
textarea {
  min-height: 65px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}
input[type="email"]:focus, input[type="number"]:focus, input[type="search"]:focus, input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="tel"]:focus, input[type="url"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus {
  border: 1px solid #33C3F0;
  outline: 0;
}
label, legend {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  border-width: 0;
}
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline;
}
label > .label-body {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .5rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}
/* Lists –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
ul {
  list-style: circle inside;
}
ol {
  list-style: decimal inside;
}
ol, ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
ul ul, ul ol, ol ol, ol ul {
  margin: 1.5rem 0 1.5rem 3rem;
  font-size: 90%;
}
li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
/* Tables –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
}
th:first-child, td:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
th:last-child, td:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}
/* Spacing –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
button, .button {
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
}
input, textarea, select, fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
}
pre, dl, figure, table, form {
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
}
p, ul, ol {
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}
/* Utilities –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.u-full-width {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.u-max-full-width {
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.u-pull-right {
  float: right;
}
.u-pull-left {
  float: left;
}
/* Misc –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
hr {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 3.5rem;
  border-width: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
}
/* Clearing –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/* Self Clearing Goodness */
.container:after, .row:after, .u-cf {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
/* Media Queries –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/* Note: The best way to structure the use of media queries is to create the queries near the relevant code. For example, if you wanted to change the styles for buttons on small devices, paste the mobile query code up in the buttons section and style it there. */
/* Larger than mobile */
@media (min-width: 400px) {
}
/* Larger than phablet (also point when grid becomes active) */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
}
/* Larger than tablet */
@media (min-width: 750px) {
}
/* Larger than desktop */
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
}
/* Larger than Desktop HD */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
}
/* Custom App CSS Below --------------------------------- */
/* Main Layout ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––*/
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
  color: #d8d8d8;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.react-entry-point{
  height: 100%;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
  font-family: "Open Sans Semi Bold";
  letter-spacing: 2.1px;
  font-size: 21px;
  padding-left: 12px;
}
p {
  font-family: "Open Sans Light";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 12px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.bg-grey{
  background-color: #31302F;
}
.text-padding{
  padding: 5px;
}
/* Graph Layout ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––*/
.div-for-charts{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
#histogram {
  flex-grow: 1
}
#map-graph {
  flex-grow: 2
}
.mapboxgl-canvas, .mapboxgl-map {
  min-width: 100%;
}
/* Graph Control Objects ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––*/
.div-user-controls {
  padding-left: 55px;
  padding-top: 64px;
}
.div-for-dropdown {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}
.div-for-slider {
  width: 97%;
  text-align: center;
}
.logo {
  height: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}
.Select-control, .Select-menu-outer, .Select-multi-value-wrapper, .select-up, .is-open .Select-control {
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
  color: white;

}

#modelselector .Select-control{
  max-height: 82px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0px 0px -3px 0px;
  border: 0.5px solid #dbdbdb44;
}

.Select-control{
  border: 0.5px solid #dbdbdb44;
}

.has-value.Select--single>.Select-control .Select-value .Select-value-label, .has-value.is-pseudo-focused.Select--single>.Select-control .Select-value .Select-value-label {
  color: white;
  background: #1E1E1E;
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
}
._dash-app-content {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.has-value.Select--single>.Select-control .Select-value .Select-value-label, .has-value.is-pseudo-focused.Select--single>.Select-control .Select-value .Select-value-labeln {
  color: #d8d8d8;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.Input.DateInput_1 {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
}

#date {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  font-family: "Open Sans Light";
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #dbdbdb;
  border: 0.5px solid #dbdbdb44;
}

#date-picker{
  width: 100%;
}

._dash-undo-redo {
  display: none;
}

.DateInput.DateInput_1{
  width: 100%;
}

.SingleDatePickerInput__withBorder{
  border:none;
}

.DateInput.DateInput_1 {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
}

.SingleDatePickerInput__withBorder {
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #dbdbdb;
  background: #1e1e1e;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
}

.SingleDatePickerInput.SingleDatePickerInput_1.SingleDatePickerInput__withBorder.SingleDatePickerInput__withBorder_2 {
  border: 0.0px solid #dbdbdb;
  display: block;
}

.SingleDatePicker_1 {
  border: 0.0px solid #dbdbdb;
  display: block;
}

.SingleDatePicker_picker, .SingleDatePicker_picker_1, .SingleDatePicker_picker__directionLeft,
.SingleDatePicker_picker__directionLeft_2{
  filter:invert(100%);
}

/* For Mobile Phones and small screens ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .four, .eight {
      min-width: 100%;
 }
  h1, h2, h3, p {
      text-align: center;
 }
  body {
      display: block;
      margin: 0px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  .div-for-charts {
      padding: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
 }

 .div-user-controls {
    padding: 32px;
 }

 .side-by-side{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
  }


 .side-by-side-right{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
    float:right;
  }
  .div-for-charts{
    margin: 0px;
  }
}

/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px !important;
  display: block !important;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #1e1e1e !important;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  display: block !important;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: transparent;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #d8d8d870 !important;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem when running `python app.py`. Do you perhaps have an accessible repository with the code that reproduces the problem which you can share?

Comment: @BasvanderLinden How can I share the repository with you?

Comment: If the repository is public you can put a link in your post

Comment: @BasvanderLinden I can send you the repository in e-mail. I dont know how to place the repository in my question.

Comment: If you have a public repository on Github for example you can just share the url of the repo which looks something like this https://github.com/user-name/repo-name.

Comment: When I am running your code while using simple values for x and y, I am getting the correct background but the only problem that I am having is that the graph is down to a point that you have to scroll to, there may be a problem with your CSS that makes the graph go down, but the  background was showing up perfectly fine for me

Comment: @BasvanderLinden Hope this works: https://github.com/KA2800/dash_app

Comment: I have checked your repo, but the background is black when I'm running it. Have you made sure the old styles aren't beeing cached, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43063755/9098350).

Comment: @BasvanderLinden Thank you bro. Done it. I had the wrong paths selected. Dankjewel :)

Answer (score 4):

The div components with class names "four columns div-user-controls" and "eight columns div-for-charts bg-grey" represent the "containers" for the sidebar and the chart, respectively. Therefore, you need to place the H2 and `html.P` as children of the sidebar `html.Div` (four columns) and the `dcc.Graph` inside the chart `html.Div` (eight column). Here's the updated code:

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import os

# Load data
df = px.data.stocks()

fig = px.line(df, x="date", y="GOOG", template="plotly_dark").update_layout(
    {"plot_bgcolor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)", "paper_bgcolor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"}
)

# Initialize the application
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# define de app
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.Div(
            className="row",
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    className="four columns div-user-controls",
                    children=[
                        html.H2("Dash - STOCK PRICES"),
                        html.P("""Visualising time series with Plotly - Dash"""),
                        html.P("""Pick one or more stocks from the dropdown below."""),
                    ],
                ),
                html.Div(
                    className="eight columns div-for-charts bg-grey",
                    children=[
                        dcc.Graph(
                            id="timeseries",
                            config={"displayModeBar": False},
                            animate=True,
                            figure=fig,
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            ],
        )
    ]
)

# Run the app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Note that I simplified the `px.line` graph since I do not have access to the CSV file you linked. Here's the end result:

[image]

Comment: I do not think that's what the original question is asking for, he wants it to look like the example he provided.

Comment: @as11 You are right. I edited the answer to correctly answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a folder in visual studio code e.g `assets`
2. Create a file in `assets` e.g. `main.css`
3. Change your python code like this:

main.css:

```
body {
  background-color: #333;
}
```

Python code:

```
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.css.append_css({"external_url": "/assets/main.css"})
app.server.static_folder = "assets"
```